# How to copy text on a ToolTip

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to use a ToolTip to display some text that users and interact with. How can I display a tooltip with text users can copy/paste or visit links. I know I can use setGraphic to add Text and Link objects, but how can I keep the tooltip open until the user clicks on something else?

Edit: I am trying to display the PopOver to the right of the TextField. As the PopOver is displayed, the user should be able to edit the TextField.

The issue I am having is when the PopOver is displayed, the user cannot make any changes to the TextField. If you try to make changes to the TextField as it is displayed, it will not let you enter any characters.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.controlsfx.control.PopOver;        

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField("Mouse mouse over me");
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea(textField.getText());
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        PopOver popOver = new PopOver(textArea);

        textField.setOnMouseEntered(mouseEvent -> {
            //Show PopOver when mouse enters label
            popOver.show(textField);
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(textField);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you use `Node` (returned from `getGraphic` or use `setGraphic` directly) to add a readonly `TextField` to the tooltip?

Comment: When I hover over the TextField, the ToolTip disappears right away. Is there a way to keep the ToolTip displayed when the mouse is over the ToolTip?

Comment: Did you try `tooltip.setAutoHide(false);`?

Comment: For a more advanced `Tooltip` use [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) [PopOver](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/PopOver.html).

Comment: It’s possible that on focus lost or mouse exit the tooltip is been closed

Comment: @Sedrick it looks like ControlsFX PopOver could work but when I use it to display next to a TextField, the TextField is no longer editable and it seems like the PopOver never loses focus back to the TextField. Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: You are going to have to post a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show what you have done and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I posted a simple example of the issue and what I am trying to achieve in the question above.